# Undo LineWrapping Effect in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have accidentally formated my code which broke almost every line in steps. I want to undo those changes. is there any solution for this :

My Previous code:

```
capsCacheDir = new File(mService.getCacheDir(),"entity-caps-cache");
```

Foramted Code :

```
capsCacheDir = new File(mService.getCacheDir(),
                        "entity-caps-cache");
```

Comment: You can always adapt the auto format rules to your liking and format again. Can't take a look which rule it is right now but I'm pretty sure there is one.

Comment: Crtl+Z - if it's too late, you can try to [comparing with/restoring from local history](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2FgettingStarted%2Fqs-55.htm) or last commit in some scm(git, mercurial, svn...) if you use one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ctrl+z or if you already saved the file go to:
Windows --> Preferences --> Java --> Code Style --> Formatter (there you can adapt the formatter rules)

Here is a link with for more help:
http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fpreferences%2Fjava%2Fcodestyle%2Fref-preferences-formatter.htm

Comment: I'd also adapt the formatter rules to your likings and then format again. Edit the profile and go to tab "Line Wrapping". There is an entry "Maximum line width" which should do what you want (set it to a pretty high value if you don't want line breaks at all).

Comment: There is an incredible amount of rules you can adapt :D